# Insert comma-separated cite references in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to achieve citing with squared brackets in natbib, having comma-separated author and year in it, like this:

```
[Einstein, 1905]
```

Within the text I am successful with:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={[},close={]}}
```

But when printing the reference with \bibliography{sample}, there is no comma between author and year. I use XeLaTex and BibTex to compile the document on macOS High Sierra.

*The sample.tex:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={[},close={]}}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{natbib} package}
\author{Share\LaTeX}
\date { }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This document is an example of \texttt{natbib} package using in bibliography
management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\citep{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \citep{einstein}, and the 
Donald Knuth's website \citep{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are 
\citep{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

*The sample.bib:*

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    year = 2019,
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

What must be done to get a comma between author and year?

**EDIT:**

The example is taken from [Sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_natbib).

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you care about the presence of a comma (or the lack thereof) in the formatted bibliography? Are you really concerned that somebody might fail to parse the formatted bib items correctly for lack of a comma? Please advise.

Comment: If I were you, I would be far more concerned about the ouright error in one of the URL strings. `url = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"` is simply wrong. It should be `url = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html"`. (Can you spot the difference?) Readers tend to resent it if they are presented with invalid URL strings. In contrast, nobody could care less over the presence (or absence) of a meaningless comma.

Comment: @Mico Well, it's about getting the document perfect all the way through. If there is a coma within the text, I'd like a comma in the references, too. Hence, the same style. And there is no place for a personal opinion when it is a thesis requirement.

Comment: @Mico True, the URL looks indeed a bit strange. I put an edit to the posting mentioning the site I got this example from. Interesting point, though not the focus of this posting.

Comment: `natbib` is a package that provides tools to manage citation call-outs. It does *not* control the look of the formatted bibliographic entries -- that's the purview of the bibliography style file (here: `dinat.bst`). You'll have to hack that file and, in particular, the BibTeX function that controls the contents of the the `\dinatlabel` directive. Are you absolutely certain that your university has made the presence of the comma in the label an absolute requirement?